# creating own registration form and storing in mysql in drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I am learning drupal on my own and doing a small project. I want a functionality where the user registration form consists of more information like age, sex, profession etc and many other fields. What module does Drupal provide for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news for you is in Drupal 7 user is an entity and a fieldable one. So it works the same way you add fields to the content type.

**So visit the account settings page: admin/config/people/accounts/fields
Create any field you want.
The trick here is in the field config form, check the little checkbox "Display on user registration form"** , and then you will have your field show up on user registration page.

Comment: The right way to thank might be to accept the answer. This will also help others to arrive at the right answer if they face the same issue and find this question.:)